# Fuzzy logic de morgan

Tags: logic, fuzzy-logic

i should show, that de morgan's law is also correct in the fuzzy logic:

$\neg(A\vee B)$ could be written as: $1-max(a,b)$

$(\neg A) \land (\neg B)$ as: $min(1-a, 1-b)$

But how could I show, that both is the same?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Bob123: Actually $a > b$ does lose some generality. I think you meant "WLOG $a \ge b$", $\ddot{\smile}$.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is:

$$\begin{align}1-\max (a,b) & = 1+\min(-a, -b) 
\\ &= \min(1-a, 1-b)
\end{align}$$

---

> Why is this possible? I do not understand this solution. –  Babs

**Reason:**
$$\begin{align}
1-\max(a, b) 
& =1 +(-1)\times\begin{cases} a & : a\geq b\\b & : a< b\end{cases}
\\ & = 1+\begin{cases}-a & : a\geq b\\-b& : a<b\end{cases}
\\ & = 1+\begin{cases}-a & : -a\leq -b\\-b & : -a<-b\end{cases} & = 1+\min(-a,-b)
\\ & = \begin{cases}1-a & : -a\leq -b\\1-b & : -a<-b\end{cases} 
\\ & = \min(1-a, 1-b)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Why is this possible? I do not understand this solution.

Comment: @Babs. Which part ?